# Separate words from a NSString which are preceded by a hashtag

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I have a NSString, for example:

```
"Had a #great time at the #party last night."
```

I want to separate this into an array, as so:

```
"Had a "
"#great"
" time at the "
"#party"
" last night."
```

How could i do this?

Comment: Which do you want to do? Removed words preceded by hash (as suggested by your subject line) or split it up into an array (as shown in the body of the question)? What's the broader objective here?

Comment: NSArray *newArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
newArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];

output:
(
    "Had a ",
    "great time at the ",
    "party last night."
)

Comment: @Pradeep But that wouldn't show me which strings had a hashtag in.

Comment: It's called an octothorpe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this regexp: `(#.+?\\b)|(.+?(?=#|$))`

It find words which begins with hashtag and subsequences which ends with hashtag

```
NSString * string = @"Had a #great time at the #party last night.";
NSError * error = nil;

NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"((#.+?\\b)|(.+?(?=#|$)))"
                                                                       options:0
                                                                         error:&error];
NSArray * matches = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches ) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [string substringWithRange:[match range]]);
}
```

Output:

```
2013-04-29 16:57:51.688 Had a 
2013-04-29 16:57:51.689 #great
2013-04-29 16:57:51.690  time at the 
2013-04-29 16:57:51.691 #party
2013-04-29 16:57:51.692  last night.
```

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *str = @"Had a #great time at the #party last night.";

NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *array = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
 NSMutableString *retStr= [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[array objectAtIndex:0]];
[arr addObject:retStr];
for(int i=1 ; i<[array count];i++)
{
    NSArray *array1 = [[array objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    {
        NSMutableString *retStr= [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        for (int i = 0;i< [array1 count]; i++)
        {
            if(i==0)
            {
                [retStr appendFormat:@" #%@ ",[array1 objectAtIndex:i]];
                [arr addObject:retStr];
                retStr= [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
            }
            else
            {
                [retStr appendFormat:@"%@ ",[array1 objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
        }
        [arr addObject:retStr];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",arr);
```

You will get the corect output as you want

Answer (score 3):

try like this it'l helps you,

```
 NSString *str=@"how are #you #friend";
    NSArray *arr=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"not SELF contains '#'"];
    NSArray *b = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
    NSLog(@"%@",b);
```

above predicate will returns the words which are not containg '#' symbol

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"not SELF like '#*'"];
```

it'l returns the words which are not started with the letter '#'

O/P:-

```
(
    how,
    are
)

EDIT:-

NSString *str=@"how are #you #friend";
    NSArray *arr=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
    NSMutableArray *result=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[arr objectAtIndex:0], nil];
    for(int i=1;i<[arr count];i++){
        [result addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%@",[arr objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

O/P:-

```
(
    "how are ",
    "#you ",
    "#friend"
)
```

Comment: That doesn't give me every string though, and show me where each entry appears.

Comment: @Andrew: once check my edited answer may be you want like this.

Comment: That's good, but in my example it would return "Had a ", "#great time at the ", "#party last night.".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it efficiently in a single pass on the string you can try something like (scratch code - test for bugs/boundary cases etc...):

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSString *msg = @"Had a #great time at the #party last night.";

    Boolean inTag = NO;
    NSMutableArray *segments = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSUInteger idx = 0;
    NSUInteger i=0;
    for (; i < [msg length]; i++)
    {
        unichar ch = [msg characterAtIndex:i];

        if (inTag && ch == ' ')
        {
            [segments addObject:[msg substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(idx, i - idx)]];
            idx = i;
            inTag = NO;
        }

        if (ch == '#')
        {
            [segments addObject:[msg substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(idx, i - idx)]];
            idx = i;
            inTag = YES;
        }
    }

    if (i > idx)
    {
        [segments addObject:[msg substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(idx, i - idx - 1)]];
    }

    for(NSString *seg in segments)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", seg);
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
2013-04-29 08:34:34.984 Craplet[95591:707] Had a 
2013-04-29 08:34:34.986 Craplet[95591:707] #great
2013-04-29 08:34:34.986 Craplet[95591:707]  time at the 
2013-04-29 08:34:34.987 Craplet[95591:707] #party
2013-04-29 08:34:34.987 Craplet[95591:707]  last night
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    for (int i=0;i<[YourArray count];i++) {
        NSString *  mystr=[YourArray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *temp=[mystr substringToIndex:1];
        if (![temp isEqualToString:@"#"]) {
           //add your string in new array and use this arry.....
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
for (int i=0;i<[YourArray count];i++) {
        NSString *  str=[YourArray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *myString=[str substringToIndex:1];
NSString *stringfinal = [myString 
   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NSString *string = @"Had a #great time at the #party last night.";
NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

NSMutableArray *formattedArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableString *mutableString = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSString *string in components)
{
    if (![string hasPrefix:@"#"]){
        if (!mutableString){
            mutableString = [NSMutableString string];
        }
        [mutableString appendFormat:@" %@",string];
    }else{
        if (mutableString) {
            [formattedArray addObject:mutableString];
            mutableString = nil;
        }
        [formattedArray addObject:string];
    }
}

if (mutableString) {
    [formattedArray addObject:mutableString];
}

NSLog(@"%@",formattedArray);
```

EDIT :

```
(
    " Had a",
    "#great",
    " time at the",
    "#party",
    " last night."
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular expressions. With this code you'll be able to extract the hashtags:

```
NSString * string = @"Had a #great time at the #party last night.";
NSError * error = nil;

NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"((?:#){1}[\\w\\d]{1,140})" options:0 error:&error];
NSArray * matches = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
for ( NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches )
{
    NSString * hashtag = [string substringWithRange:[match range]];
    NSLog(@"match: %@", hashtag);
}
```

With this, you'll be able to build up the array result you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One-pass solution with [NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSString *string = @"Had a #great time at the #party last night.";
NSMutableArray *array = [@[] mutableCopy];
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    NSString *s;

    [scanner scanUpToString:@"#" intoString:&s];
    if(s) [array addObject:s];
    s = nil;

    [scanner scanUpToString:@" " intoString:&s];
    if(s) [array addObject:s];        
}
```

---

result:

```
(
    "Had a ",
    "#great",
    "time at the ",
    "#party",
    "last night."
)
```

---

if you want to preserve the leading whitespace, alter it slightly to

```
NSString *string = @"Had a #great time at the #party last night.";
NSMutableArray *array = [@[] mutableCopy];
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];

BOOL firstSegment = YES;
while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    NSString *s;
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"#" intoString:&s];
    if(s) [array addObject: (!firstSegment) ? [@" " stringByAppendingString:s] : s];
    s = nil;

    [scanner scanUpToString:@" " intoString:&s];
    if(s) [array addObject:s];
    firstSegment = NO;
}
```

---

result:

```
(
    "Had a ",
    "#great",
    " time at the ",
    "#party",
    " last night."
)
```